# Configure Truststore in Tomcat

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7

I have a Java servlet currently running on Tomcat 7 (Windows) and it connects to a SQL Server database.  I now need to encrypt this connection and I have a public Key SSL certificate in a keystore.  But apparently I have to configure a system property for a *"Truststore"* and have the truststore set to the keystore.

The keystore location is C:\SSLKeys\appkeystore.key and from what I have found I have to set the Truststore up with the following;

```
Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\SSLKeys\appkeystore.key
Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=appkeystorePassword
```

But how do I set these please?  I have tried it in the command line but that doesn't seem to work.  I don't want to hard code these in the Java as I need them to be configurable.

Can these be set in the `Catalina.bat` file in Tomcat?  If so where in the file do I put the command?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think I may have found how, or at least one way of doing this.  Someone please tell me if there is a better way of processing this.  In the Tomcat\bin folder, where the catalina.bat file is I created a setenv.bat file and in there I declared the two Java option properties for;

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\path\to\keystore.key" "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=************"
```

Apparently when Tomcat is started it initiates the catalina.bat file and the catalina.bat file determines if a setenv.bat file exists and if so runs this file to set the Java options.

Again someone please correct me if I am wrong and advise of any better way of doing this.  Although apparently where Tomcat is set up as a Windows service the options above are input through the tomcatXw.exe to initiate the Tomcat console and the Java tab is selected.

Comment: But in this case, trustStorePassword will be visible when you do a ps -ef | grep 'javax.net.ssl'. Ideally, ssl details should be put in a separate properties file which should be referred in catalina.sh or setenv.sh.

Comment: He's using set so there's no PS in windows :D

Comment: For me in Windows, I have to create setenv.bat and enter set JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\path\to\keystore.key . I had to remove all quotes for it to work

Answer (score 14):

Incase anybody else is having this question, here is what I did:
1. Navigate to \tomcatDirectory\bin\
2. Edit the catalina.sh/bat depending on you machine.
3. Add these properties to the JAVA_OPTS property

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$CATALINA_HOME/certificates/truststore.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststorePassword -server"
```

This will essentially tell tomcat to use the specified truststore instead of the default **cacerts** truststore which tomcat loads if it does not find any truststore specified in the system properties.

Also, I have noticed that it is possible to define the truststore in tomcat's main configuration file **server.xml**. All you have to do is set these properties in the ***connector*** property.

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="500"
           server="Apache"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="500"
           keystoreFile="/apps/content/certificates/keystore.ks" keystorePass="keystorepass"
           truststoreFile="/apps/content/certificates/truststore.ks" truststorePass="truststorePassword"/>
```

Try it out, Hope it helps!

Comment: The purposes of the key/truststore settings in `JAVA_OPTS` and in the `Connector` are different.

Comment: Oh! okay, I have never really tried the second approach so I wouldn't really know about that. It was just something I noticed while messing around with tomcat configurations. Thanks for the correction by the way!

Comment: Basically, the truststore parameters in `Connector` are for setting which client certificates you want to trust. The `javax.net.ssl.*` settings in `JAVA_OPTS` affect the default SSL context (typically for connection made from within the servlets, where they act as clients, for example).

Comment: Editing the catalina.sh file is not recommended. In fact the file even says specifically how to do it: `Do not set the variables in this script [catalina.sh]. Instead put them into a script setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.`

Comment: Which java tomcat will use by default ?

Comment: I was using TeamCity on Windows and editing the Catalina.bat in <TC install directory>\bin\ to add the parameters as you said got rid of this error. The cacerts file is in <TC install directory>\jre\lib\security. Then I needed to add my org's cert to the cacerts file which was done by following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

Answer (score 3):

The recommended answer only works for Tomcat deployed in Windows, I found that the below works for me in **Linux** server:

TOMDOGEDIRECTORY/bin/**setenv.sh** [*You need to create this file yourself*]

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/meh_tuststove.jks" 
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=muchsecure" 
export JAVA_OPTS
```

Comment: Now it is better CATALINA_OPTS instead

Comment: do i really need to mention the password ? I mean  javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword . 
     While trying in ide ( eclipse or IntelliJ ) i can use it just by -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore .  
     please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `server.xml` file for this. You can find it in `conf/` directory.

First uncomment these lines:

```xml
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->
```

and then change it something like this

```xml
<Connector SSLEnabled           ="true"
           acceptCount          ="100"
           clientAuth           ="false"
           disableUploadTimeout ="true"
           enableLookups        ="false"
           maxThreads           ="25"
           port                 ="8443"
           keystoreFile         ="C:\SSLKeys\appkeystore.key"
           keystorePass         ="password"
           protocol             ="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           scheme               ="https"
           secure               ="true"
           sslProtocol          ="TLS"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks celezar.  But I already have the "keystoreFile" parameter set up in the server.xml connector tag.  So this hasn't made any difference.  From what I have found so far it appears I have to declare some sort of Java system property to create a "Truststore" using a command like Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\SSLKeys\appkeystore.key" but there is no exact tutorial on how to do this.  I tried it in the command line but that didn't work.

Comment: Your answer is about configuring TLS enabled *connector*, which accepts *incoming* connections, but the question is about trusting certificates of *outgoing* connections, i.e. when servers connects to database—totally different thing

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat 9 truststore can be added in **server.xml** as follows

```
<Connector port="<portOnWhichHttpsToBeEnabled>" SSLEnabled="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
               keystoreFile="KEYSTORE_PATH"
               keystorePass="KEYSTORE_PWD"
               truststoreFile="TRUSTSTORE_PATH"
               truststorePass="TRUSTSTORE_PWD"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Note: clientAuth must be set to true

For tomcat 10 and above, it can be added as follows

Step 1: Add the keystore as follows in **server.xml**

```
<Connector port="<portOnWhichHttpsToBeEnabled>" SSLEnabled="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
              >
      <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate
            certificateKeyAlias="KEYSTORE_ALIAS"
            certificateKeystoreFile=""KEYSTORE_PATH""
            certificateKeystorePassword="KEYSTORE_PWD"
            type="RSA"
        />
      </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Step 2: then add trust store as follows in **setenv.sh**

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=TRUSTORE_PATH -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=TRUSTSTORE_PWD"
```

In tomcat logs you can find that the trust store is loaded as follows

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.logCertificate Connector [https-openssl-nio-<portOnWhichHttpsToBeEnabled>], TLS virtual host [_default_], certificate type [RSA] configured from keystore [KEYSTORE_PATH] using alias [KEYSTORE_ALIAS] with trust store [TRUSTORE_PATH]
```