# How to enable TLS 1.2 in local Tomcat?

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I am trying to enable TLS 1.2 in application side because the database server and the database instance now supports TLS 1.2 so I have to be align with that from the application side. I’ve added a property `sslEnabledProtocols=”TLSv1.2”` in the server.xml file which is inside the server folder in my STS IDE. I also have the mssql-jdbc 6.4.0 jar and I am using JDK 7 with Tomcat 7. For some reason I am getting `C:\Users\myName/.keystore due to C:\Users\ssadat\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)` exception. I am not sure what else is missing.

Server.xml

[image]

Stacktrace
[image]

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833732/configure-truststore-in-tomcat)

Comment: just curious how do you come to add tag 'sql-server'

Comment: because the app talks to sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable TLS , you need to give the details of the certificate which it will search in a keystone.
By default it's searching in your home directory for a keystore folder.
So you should create a keystore, generate certificate and configure it's path in server.xml file

Comment: How can I create a keystore?

Comment: Simple search will tell you 
for reference- httpss://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19636-01/819-1655/fapsf/index.html